# Run a command prompt code using vbs

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have a line of code that works in command prompt. All it does it close the "Personalization" window when it is open. The code is as follows:

```
taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Personalization"
```

I want to create a very short (only a few lines) vbs code that, when executed, will run the line through cmd. I have tried using Shell functions but this is not working for me for some reason. Does anyone know how to do this? I feel it should be simple, as I know how to open cmd using vbscript, but the syntax I use is incorrect in having cmd execute that line.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: I had tried using this: 'Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run = "cmd /c "taskkill /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Personalization""' but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "taskkill /fi ""WINDOWTITLE eq Personalization""", 0, true
```

Instantiate a `Shell` object and use its `Run` method to execute the indicated command

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works! But I am pretty new to vbscript. I am a recent ME grad and have loved coding but in VBA and Matlab only and have recently started trying new languages. How come you added extra quotation marks around the windowtitle part? And I understand the 0 means "hide" the window, but why do you have to add the "true" statement at the end?

Comment: @art123456, in vbs, inside a "quoted" string, to include a quote character you need to double it. Yes, the 0 in *windowStyle* is hide it. The `True` parameter is *waitOnReturn*, to wait for the started process to end before continue (false is not to wait). No being sure how it will be used, it is safer to wait than to continue not knowing if the next code asumes the taskkill has ended.

Comment: You actually have just answered another question that I haven't even asked but have been trying to figure out as well! Wow thank you that's awesome! Well now it works, I wish I had joined earlier and gotten points so I could upvote your response, but unfortunately I am unable to as I joined today :/